# JQuery animation in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have such code:

```
$('div.new_menu').hover(function(){ 
      $(this).stop(false, true).animate({width: $(this).width() + 25}, 450); 
   },function(){ 
      $(this).stop(false, true).animate({width: $(this).width() - 25}, 450); 
   });
```

It works perfect in all browsers except IE. Could you help me with rewriting it to JavaScript?

Comment: jQuery **is** JavaScript

Comment: I mean rewrite script without JQuery library. Clean javascript.

Comment: Rewriting the code to avoid using a normalization/helper library isn't the solution. Identifying the bug and fixing it is the solution.

Comment: I bet the problem is that `$(this).width()` is returning something that doesn't look like a number. If that's the case, you're going to have to deal with it, jQuery or no jQuery. (Check @rahul's answer below - that approach lets jQuery deal with it!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try giving the first parameter to `stop()` as `true`. Also change the width as relative

> Animated properties can also be
>   relative. If a value is supplied with
>   a leading += or -= sequence of
>   characters, then the target value is
>   computed by adding or subtracting the
>   given number from the current value of
>   the property.

```
$('div.new_menu').hover(function(){ 
      $(this).stop(true, true).animate({width: '+=25'}, 450); 
   },function(){ 
      $(this).stop(true, true).animate({width: '-=25'}, 450); 
   });
```